# Watermark Image Appears dark on first page only

Tags: watermark

I am adding a watermark logo to my document. I have used this before and it worked with no problem. However, recently when I went to recompile to document, it is showing the full picture on the first page, but the opaque picture on all other pages. How do I get the opaque on the first page back? Here is the code I am using. This previously worked, but is no longer working for an unknown reason. I haven't changed the code at all.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=myblack,
opacity=0.1,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo-02}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Some stuff here
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I replace the image with one from the mwe package and add a second page, I don't see a difference between the background images. Can you add a screenshot of the result you get and show your .log file so we can which package versions you have etc.

Comment: you are asking about the behaviour on the second page but provide a single page example that is not useful also please use `example-image` as that is generally available for tests like this